# Upgrade Apache Solr version 7 to 9 without re-indexing

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud

**I want to upgrade Solr 7.3 to Solr 9.1**

But I want to make this upgrade without re-indexing my existing documents. (the schema in my v7 is compatible to v9)

Research I have done lead me to the tool "IndexUpgraderTool", it's a tool by Solr that allow you to fix your existing index to be compatible to the new major version. Each version come with this tool that can fix the prev version index.

To my question -> is it possible to take Solr 8 IndexUpgraderTool and run it before solr 9 starting, then run the Solr 9 IndexUpgraderTool?

Comment: In theory yes. But you have to try and run tests, don't do it blindly. Though it's strongly recommend to reindex your data completely.